LSTM With DiffSharp
I'm trying to convert the full code of the example shown on this webpage: https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-for-time-series-prediction-in-pytorch/ which involves implementation of an LSTM.
My code looks as follows:
#r "nuget: DiffSharp-cpu"
#r "nuget: Deedle"

// Load necessary libraries
open DiffSharp
open DiffSharp.Compose
open DiffSharp.Model
open DiffSharp.Optim
open DiffSharp.Data
open Deedle
open System

// Set DiffSharp configuration
dsharp.config(backend=Backend.Torch, device=Device.CPU)
dsharp.seed(0)

// Load CSV using Deedle
let df = Frame.ReadCsv(@"airline-passengers.csv")

let timeseries = 
    df?Passengers
    |> Series.values
    |> Array.ofSeq
    |> Array.map float32

// Train-test split for time series
let trainSize = int (float (Array.length timeseries) * 0.67)
let testSize = (Array.length timeseries) - trainSize
let train = Array.sub timeseries 0 trainSize
let test = Array.sub timeseries trainSize testSize

// Function to create dataset
let createDataset (dataset: float32[]) lookback =
    let X, y = ResizeArray<float32[]>(), ResizeArray<float32[]>()
    for i in 0 .. (Array.length dataset) - lookback - 1 do
        let feature = Array.sub dataset i lookback
        let target = Array.sub dataset (i + 1) lookback
        X.Add feature
        y.Add target
    dsharp.tensor(X.ToArray()).unsqueeze(-1), dsharp.tensor(y.ToArray()).unsqueeze(-1)

// Define lookback
let lookback = 4

// Create train and test datasets
let X_train, y_train = createDataset train lookback
let X_test, y_test = createDataset test lookback

// Print shapes to verify
printfn "X_train shape: %A" X_train.shape
printfn "y_train shape: %A" y_train.shape
printfn "X_test shape: %A" X_test.shape
printfn "y_test shape: %A" y_test.shape

let model = 
    LSTM(1, 50, 1, false, true)
    --> Linear(50, 1)
    --> dsharp.relu

// Define the AirModel in DiffSharp
// type AirModel() as this =
//     inherit Model()
//     let lstm = LSTM(1, 50, 1, false, true)
//     let linear = Linear(50, 1)
      
//     override this.forward(x) =
//         x
//         |> lstm.forward
//         |> linear.forward

//let model = new AirModel()
// Print the model summary
printfn "Model\n%s" (model.summary())
let optimizer = Adam(model, lr=dsharp.tensor(0.001))

// Load your data (assuming X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test are already defined as Tensors)
// Define the training data loader
let trainData = TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
let trainLoader = trainData.loader(batchSize=lookback, shuffle=true)

// Training loop
let epochs = 10

for epoch = 1 to epochs do
    model.mode <- Mode.Train
    
    for i, xBatch, yBatch in trainLoader.epoch() do
        let yPred = model.forward(xBatch)
        let loss = dsharp.mseLoss(yPred, yBatch)
        //printfn "Batch %d: xBatch shape: %A, yBatch shape: %A, yPred shape: %A" i xBatch.shape yBatch.shape yPred.shape
        
        model.reverseDiff()
        loss.reverse()
        optimizer.step()
        printfn $"Epoch {epoch}/{epochs}, batch {i}/{trainLoader.length}, loss: {loss.toSingle()}"

The training loop only executes if I comment out loss.reverse() and optimizer.step()
Otherwise I get the following error message:
System.Exception: Expecting dim=2 when no specific dimensions are given to transpose. Consider using general transpose(dim0, dim1).           
   at DiffSharp.ShapeModule.checkCanTranspose2d(Int32 dim)             
   at DiffSharp.Tensor.transpose()                                     
   at <StartupCode$DiffSharp-Core>.$Tensor.push@2836(FSharpList`1 ts)  
   at DiffSharp.Tensor.reversePush(Tensor value)                       
   at DiffSharp.Tensor.reverse(FSharpOption`1 value, FSharpOption`1 zeroDerivatives)                                                          
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0041>.$FSI_0041.main@() in d:\Martin\Coding\F#\DiffSharp Example5.fsx:line 1997                                        
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)                          
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)                                               
Stopped due to error   

If I comment out optimizer.step(), I get the following error message:
System.Exception: Expecting dim=2 when no specific dimensions are given to transpose. Consider using general transpose(dim0, dim1).           
   at DiffSharp.ShapeModule.checkCanTranspose2d(Int32 dim)             
   at DiffSharp.Tensor.transpose()                                     
   at <StartupCode$DiffSharp-Core>.$Tensor.push@2836(FSharpList`1 ts)  
   at DiffSharp.Tensor.reversePush(Tensor value)                       
   at DiffSharp.Tensor.reverse(FSharpOption`1 value, FSharpOption`1 zeroDerivatives)                                                          
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0043>.$FSI_0043.main@() in d:\Martin\Coding\F#\DiffSharp Example5.fsx:line 1997                                        
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)                          
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)                                               
Stopped due to error 

If I comment out loss.reverse(), I get the following error message:
System.Exception: shapes [|0|] and [||] are not related by broadcasting - each dimension must either be extra, equal, expand from 1           
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1448.Invoke(String message)                                              
   at DiffSharp.Tensor.op_Multiply(Tensor a, Tensor b)                 
   at DiffSharp.Optim.Adam.updateRule(String name, Tensor t)           
   at <StartupCode$DiffSharp-Core>.$Optim.step@30.Invoke(Tuple`2 tupledArg)                                                                   
   at DiffSharp.Model.ParameterDict.iter(FSharpFunc`2 f)               
   at DiffSharp.Optim.Optimizer.step()                                 
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0044>.$FSI_0044.main@() in d:\Martin\Coding\F#\DiffSharp Example5.fsx:line 1998                                        
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)                          
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)                                               
Stopped due to error   
``
Tensor shapes are as follows:
X_train shape: [|92; 4; 1|]                                            
y_train shape: [|92; 4; 1|]                                            
X_test shape: [|44; 4; 1|]                                             
y_test shape: [|44; 4; 1|]                                             

Any ideas what can be wrong?

